# How do I correctly stop a Media Player in a CountDown Timer when the activity is Paused?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

I can successfully cancel the Countdown Timer before it finishes when the activity is paused. However, the media player implemented in the OnTick method of the canceled timer doesn't stop for  5-8 seconds. What would be the correct way to disable the sound of the media player in the CountDown Timer when the activity is paused?

```
private Button soundOn;
private Button soundOff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one);



   SharedPreferences savedSoundToggle = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_SOUNDTOGGLE, 0);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor soundEditor = savedSoundToggle.edit();

    nSound = savedSoundToggle.getInt("SoundOnorOff", 0);


    if(nSound == 1){
        soundOff.setEnabled(false);
        soundOff.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        soundOn.setEnabled(true);
        soundOn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if( nSound == 0){
        soundOn.setEnabled(false);
        soundOn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        soundOff.setEnabled(true);
        soundOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

public void OneGame(){

  final MediaPlayer intro = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.minicycleaudio);
  final MediaPlayer go = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.flashgoaudio);

  getReadyTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            getReadyTimeText.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            if(soundOn.isEnabled()){
                intro.start();
            }
            if(soundOff.isEnabled()){
                if(intro.isPlaying()){
                    intro.pause();
                }
            }
         }

          public void onFinish() {

            if(intro.isPlaying()) {
                intro.stop();
                intro.release();
            }
             if(soundOn.isEnabled()) {
                go.start();
            }


@Override
public void onPause() {

  super.onPause();
  getReadyTimer.cancel();

  }
}
```

I'm almost 100% positive that the Countdown timer becomes canceled when the activity is paused because the media player in the onFinish() function is never called. Why does the media player in the onTick method keep playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: To cancel a media player in a CountDown Timer, when the activity is paused... you must declare the MediaPlayer as static, not final.

```
static  MediaPlayer intro;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one);
    getReadyTimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelonetimerText);

 public void OneGame(){
    intro = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.minicycleaudio);


}
```